# Fancyselect interrups change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin for my select box:
http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/

But when I started using that my .change functions started to not work. Do I have to do this another way now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see from the code, it fires a `change.fs` event so use that

```
$(selector).fancySelect().on('change.fs', function () {
    console.log('change.fs', this.value)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fP2eb/)

Comment: Thank you it worked! I did read the manual but I just couldn't understand it sorry. All I had to do is change "change" to "change.fs"

Comment: @SinanSamet I didn't go through the manual just saw the plugin source